# What does ?: in a regular expression mean?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

Please explain the meaning of this regular expression and what groups the expression will generate?

```
$string =~ m/^(\d*)(?: \D.*?)(\d*)$/
```

PS: I'm re-factoring Perl code to Java.

Comment: `(?:...)` is non capturing group.

Comment: `123 fdhdhf234` for this input , 1st capturing group index contains 123 and the second capturing group index contains 234.

Comment: @AvinashRaj When i run this code `perl -e '$string="123fdhdhf234"; $string =~ m/^(\d*)(?: \D.*?)(\d*)$/; print $1; print $2;'` Nothing gets printed.

Comment: Yes, because there is no space after the first three digits. This regex `^(\d*)(?: \D.*?)(\d*)$` would match the string only if it's  starts with a number followed by a space or a space.

Comment: Sorry for the bother.. Thanks @AvinashRaj !

Comment: You should always check if match was suceful `perl -e '$string="123fdhdhf234"; print $1, $2 if $string =~ m/^(\d*)(?: \D.*?)(\d*)$/;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that it is not capturing group. After successful match first `(\d*)` will be captured in `$1`, and second in `$2`, and `(?: \D.*?)` would not be captured at all.

```
$string =~ m/^(\d*)(?: \D.*?)(\d*)$/
```

From [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings)

> *Non-capturing groupings*
>
> A group that is required to bundle a set of alternatives may or may not be useful as a capturing group. If it isn't, it just creates a superfluous addition to the set of available capture group values, inside as well as outside the regexp. Non-capturing groupings, denoted by **(?:regexp)**, still allow the regexp to be treated as a single unit, but don't establish a capturing group at the same time.